# How to use boost websocket to implement sub-protocol

Tags: boost-beast, beast-websockets

I want to implement a websocket sub-protocol.
For example, I have a weboscket server as ws://localhost:1234, now I need one more sub-protocol as ws://localhost:1234/sub.

I know lib-websockets provides this function, but I haven't found it in boost websocket.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: "boost websocket" were you talking about Boost.Beast?

Comment: see whether this could help https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/example/http/server/async/http_server_async.cpp

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/examples.html
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/examples.html#beast.examples.servers